# Angular domain models

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Currently I am working on angular app that is generate through Angular CLI & it is using webpack.

We have 50+ model typescript classes to hold data such as employee.model.ts , person.model.ts etc.

In our project currently it is scattered all over the place in different modules. We decided to put all the models into one angular module & then all other modules should be importing these domain models from one particular module.

How do I achieve this ?

I have read couple of posts regarding typescript alias feature where in tsconfig.json file I could add path property. So here is what I have tried so far.

```
ProjectDirectory/src/app

ProjectDirectory/src/app/models
```

Models folder contains employee.model.ts , person.model.ts & 50+ other models.

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@my-models/*": ["models/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Import statement I tried on other component.

```
import { Employee } from '@my-models'; //<== DOESN'T WORK & THROWS ERROR.
```

Error

```
src/app/app.module.ts (20,26): Cannot find module '@my-models'.
```

Is there any clean way to organize all models in one place & have cleaner import statements that does not have relative paths such as

```
import {Xyz} from './././././abc.module';
```

Thanks everyone in advance to take time to read the question.

Note : I read following articles but it did not work.

https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: You can create a re-usable angular module. Look at ng-packagr:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr for an easy way to do this. However, are you sure you want to do this? The Google style guide and the LIFT principle (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#lift) recommends going away from the traditional approach of having all your models in one place, all your services in one place, etc.  Instead, keep code that is functionally related as close together as possible.

Comment: When you follow LIFT, you'll find that there is no need to have so many nested import statements (i.e. the problem with `import {...} from '../../../../../../some.module'` goes away)

Comment: Thank you pixelbits to pointing me into the right direction.However we have certain domain models that can be used from different services located in different modules which returns the same model. We do not want to duplicate such models in every module.That is why I am looking for some solution where I could have cleaner import statements regardless of in which module I need such domain model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach to handling this is by using a [**barrel**](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel).

In your `models` folder you can add an `index.ts` file which exports all the classes contained in that folder:

```
export * from './abc.module.ts';   // re-export all of its exports
export * from './xyz.module.ts'; // re-export all of its exports
...
```

now what needs to be imported comes from the barrel:

```
import { Abc, Xyz } from './path-to-models';
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the question.I think this can definitely  help in my scenario. I could create a folder called models & put all of them inside & create barrel as you have mentioned. However one part that remains unanswered is how to get pretty import statements such as `import {xyz,abc} from '@mycompanyname-models'`.  This would work regardless of the location of the typescript file in which I am writing the import statement. Is this still possible ?

Comment: I believe it should still be possible, although I have not tested this myself. Reading through [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1465) and in particular, [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1465#issuecomment-350019210), with the right configuration in your `tsconfig.json` it should work, although there seem to be issues with AOT.

Comment: Thanks  @Und3rTow. Worked perfectly fine after following the suggestion you mentioned & suggestions made on the github links you posted. I really appreciate your help.